# Timed drawing with Direct2D?

Tags: c++, direct2d

I have been having a lot of fun with Direct2D in the past few days, painting my own images in layers and such onto a window and creating buttons. However, I have two questions regarding the use of timers and this API:

1. Is it possible to delay the painting of an object for, say, five seconds? I have tried using `Sleep()` and C++ timers within the window procedure but have found no success - only hangs as the function tries to call a wait function.
2. How can I write text using `DirectWrite` or `DrawText` a character at a time so that the text seems to "appear" as if it was being written left-to-right? I had a functional approach in the console by using `Sleep()` after a call to `WriteConsoleCharacter()` but this approach does not seem to work in `WinMain` working with the Windows API.

If anyone has any experience working with these sort of ideas I would appreciate a point in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: You can't use `Sleep` in a GUI application because it will block the main thread, and it is important that you continually process messages. You might consider building a queue of actions and as the time for each passes execute the action. [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) could be useful for that or keep it sorted by timestamp and in each iteration of the message loop pop off and execute them until you hit one that is for a future time.

Comment: Typically, you have to draw everything that you want to be on the screen at the current time. Then, after some time passed, you draw everything that you want to be on the screen at *that* current time. And so on. Typically 60 times a second.

Comment: I thought that was the reason for the hangs. I will do some reading into the `SetTimer()` function. @user253751 Where can I read about this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible.

However, as mentioned by someone else you shouldn't use `Sleep()` in order to do that.

You can use `QueryPerformanceCounter()` to do precise timer. There are many different approach, but I suggest this one.

Comment: Hmm. This looks like an interesting function. I suppose one could divide the returned value by 10^10 (ten-million) to get a seconds value and use this as a comparison value to determine draw times. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: *10E10, pardon me.
**10E6, even worse. Pardon me.

Comment: @nore anyway, sorry I don't have time to give you an example.